# Mono for Android: Application wide theme

Tags: xamarin.android, android-theme

I'm new to Mono for Android (using MonoDevelop) and Android development in general. I want to create a application wide theme. This theme only has to set the background color of all EditText fields gray (just to test the functionality).

In the Resources/values folder I created 2 files:

Styles.xml

```
<resources>
<style name="tstEditText" parent="android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">#cccccc</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Themes.xml

```
<resources>
<style name="MyApplicationTheme" parent="android:Theme">    
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/txtEditText</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

After that I modified the ApplicationManifest.xml

```
<application android:label="MyApplication" android:theme="MyApplicationTheme"></application>
```

When I try to build the code I get the following error message: "**Error: String types not allowed (at 'theme' with value 'MyApplicationTheme').**" The error is thrown on the first activity node in the AndroidManifest.xml that is generated on build by MonoDevelop.

Apparently I'm missing something, but I have no clue...
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the manifest XML you need to specify the theme like this:

```
android:theme="@style/MyApplicationTheme"
```